# Replace an image in a PDF using command line

Tags: command-line, pdf, images

I need to process some PDF files. The task consists in exchange a given image file by another. My first problem is how to replace a PDF image from command line in a batch process. Next I'll try to address other problems like how to identify which is the image I need to replace (because the PDF files may have more than one image). But first I want to resolve the first problem: how to replace a image in a PDF by another.

I've read about poppler-utils and pdftk but as far as I Know, none of these tools allow to replace images into PDF.

Comment: If you find an answer it will be really interesting to know. After isolating the "problem page", you could use ImageMagick to insert an image into another and then convert it back to pdf: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/  Also: http://superuser.com/questions/614784/how-to-batch-process-every-image-in-a-pdf-using-commandline-tools

Comment: Thanks @pidosaurus I was cosidering this options but it has a big problem: it implies to convert the PDF (or the signature page) to images. It's a problem because the resulting PDF will be much bigger in size and the user couldn't select a piece of text to copy and paste for instance.

Comment: lookup convert from imagemagick, and more so, the tools that ooconv from openoffice (now libreoffice, actually) provide -- I once hired someone to write a PPT to PDF convertor and these were the tools used.

Comment: None of the PDF tools I know is able to do that, but it wouldn't be very hard to write a new tool using a PDF library with that functionality. One problem you'll have to solve is *how to specify* a particular image in a PDF.

Answer (score 2):

OK ... I think `pdflatex` is the missing piece here.

The OP said he has looked into `poppler-utils` and `pdftk`.  Let me add to that `pdfimages`.  These, together with `pdflatex` are the pieces of a solution.

```
pdfimages -f 4 -l 20 -j -png target.pdf imageroot
```

In the example code above, `pdfimages`  looks through pages 4 through 20 of `target.pdf` and extracts all images into files with names beginning `imageroot`.

`poppler-utils` provides `pdftotext`.  I recommend the `-layout` option which does a great job keeping the document human readable.

```
pdftotext -layout $1.pdf $1.txt
```

The OP's objection to the `imagemagick` solution offered by *pidosaurus* is that
an image does not have extractable text.  With the utilities I outlined, the OP will now have all the images as well as all the extracted text, and page numbers and contents are retained by the `-layout` option.  The OP could identify the correct page of text and chuck it into a `.tex` file which ends with an `%includegraphics` directive and refers to the replacement picture by filename.  You then `pdflatex` this and end up with a new single-page .pdf to insert into the rest of your document with `pdftk`.  If you knew where in the text of the original page the image resided, you can `%includegraphics [h]` and get the image in exactly the right place.

Comment: Sorry, this is no solution to the question. You forget that the layout could be arbitrarily complicated. A somewhat better (but still to inaccurate) solution would be to convert the PDF to an SVG file and then make the changes and convert back. But this also has losses.

The thing is: If the images can be extracted, it should also be possible to replace an image by another one. At least of another one with the same x-y-dimensions. Or even better with the same filesize (like an uncompressed image).

Comment: This is a (great) solution. It superimposes the new image upon the page, so it doesn't cause loss of quality. It allows the whole process to be scripted, once the missing piece is supplied, namely, automatic location of a given image on a given page, which can probably be done [with ImageMagick](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=28319) or [with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853628/how-do-i-find-an-image-contained-within-an-image).

Answer (score 1):

If a simple python script is adequate enough for you, then the solution is easy with the [pdfrw library](https://pypi.org/project/pdfrw/).

A simple working example:

```py
#!/bin/python

import pdfrw

# Read the example pdf file originating from:
# https://getsamplefiles.com/download/pdf/sample-3.pdf
reader = pdfrw.PdfReader('sample-3.pdf')

# Opening the new image file originating from:
# https://www.picserver.org/assets/library/2020-10-31/originals/example1.jpg
with open('example1.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    # Overwriting the desired image in the original pdf structure.
    reader.Root.Pages.Kids[0].Resources.XObject['/X9'].stream = f.read().decode('latin')

# Write the modified pdf file out.
pdfrw.PdfWriter('sample-3_out.pdf', trailer=reader).write()
```

Used example files from [here (pdf)](https://getsamplefiles.com/download/pdf/sample-3.pdf), and [here (jpg)](https://www.picserver.org/assets/library/2020-10-31/originals/example1.jpg).

Finding the right image element in the pdf structure might be a bit tricky but there is a very useful tool to inspect the pdf structure called [pdfalyzer](https://pypi.org/project/pdfalyzer/).

Use pdfalyze with -t flag for tree view, or -r flag for rich tree view like this:

`pdfalyze --maximize-width -r sample-3.pdf | less -R`

As I learned the `/Filter /DCTDecode` in the pdf structure means jpg image data and `/Filter /FlateDecode` means gzip compressed data. There can be multiple filters for a stream data and there are more filters than these two.

[More about pdf structure.](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010035745/http://gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify a bit, do you have an enormous set of .pdf files, and a list of image names in some of those files that need to be replaced, but you need a quick way to find each image that needs replacing without opening every .pdf file in the directory?

If I were in your shoes and unable to dedicate enough time to finding /developing a code-based solution, I would try some batch processes in Inkscape. This is off the top of my head, but...

1. Make a copy of all the pdf files you're working with
2. Open a pdf into Inkscape, and use a Transform/Scale command to reduce the dimensions (and reduce file size). Test to see how small you can make the pdf page and still recognize the images.
3. Use a batch command to Transform / Scale the file size of all the pdfs in the copied directory. You may also be able to use a batch process to enable some kind of image optimization or other process to reduce each file size.
4. Open a set of 20 or so at a time into Inkscape (drag and drop?), and visually scan for the images that need to be replaced.
5. By clicking on the pdf in Inkscape, you should be able to get the filename or ascertain it based on its stacked order, then go open and swap images in the original.

In the worst case scenario, grunt work = podcast time.